# Oracle Cloud How to get Shipping Notes for a Shipment

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-bi

I have a shipment that contains Notes.  I know the shipment headers are in `WSH_NEW_DELIVERIES` table, and notes are in `ZMM_NOTES` table.  I can't find any information to how to join this two tables (ie notes for a particular shipment). There are `NOTE_ID`, `SOURCE_OBJECT_UID`columns in `ZMM_NOTES`.  But to which table should I join it to?

[image: Oracle BI Publisher Front End]

The table structures are below:

[ZMM_NOTES](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/farel9/salescs_gs/OEDMS/ZMM_NOTES_tbl.htm)

[WSH_NEW_DELIVERIES](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/scmcs_gs/OEDSC/WSH_NEW_DELIVERIES_tbl.htm)

Comment: Structure of both tables will be appreciated, also, have you looked into the table's foreign key constraints? just to (hopefully) get a hint on which one references the primary key of the other. Or perhaps look for a third table which acts as an intermediate between the two you mentioned.

Comment: Is `ZMM_NOTES` a detail table? field `PARENT_NOTE_ID` suggests a master table with complementary info and possibly a relation with your deliveries header table.

Comment: @JairHernandez `PARENT_NOTE_ID` is blank.  The problem I have is finding the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: I can only think of two options here, those `attribute` fields containing the keys to relate the tables, or simply that this two tables have nothing that can establish a relation between them and you should seek somewhere else for it. It's hard with no actual data to analyze.